# SharePoint App Calendar not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, android, sharepoint-onlineapp

SharePoint online, I have a Calendar with a custom content type based on Event type, I downloaded the SharePoint App on Android and logged in to my site using multifactor authentication, searched for the calendar, opened, and at the bottom of the calendar I get "Could not connect to the service something went wrong" and the calendar is non-functional

Comment: could you please provide more information? Is it SharePoint app? on andriod or IOS? what SharePoint version u are using? what authentication method?

Comment: So this is SharePoint online, I have a Calendar with a custom content type based on Event type, I downloaded the SharePoint App on Android and logged in to my site using multifactor authentication, searched for the calendar, opened, and at the bottom of the calendar I get "Could not connect to the service something went wrong" and the calendar is non-functional.